# How to check the HISTORY of Docker Container Restarts

Tags: docker

I'm trying to find the history of container restarts.

Of course the `STATUS` field on a `docker ps` will show the current uptime.

However if I have a container with a restart policy such as `restart: unless-stopped` and it's gone through several restarts - **How can I check that restart/uptime history?**

If the docker engine doesn't natively track this - is there a known good method to handle this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can view the docker events. E.g. this will show all restart events for the last hour:

```
docker events --filter event=restart --since=60m
```

For more details on docker events, see: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events

Comment: I must have missed it in the documentation. Thank you!

Comment: `docker events` doesn't print anything for me. I had to use it with `--since` to get a result, meaning e.g.: `docker events --since 2020-01-01`  (or just `--since 2020`)

Comment: @MacMartin I'm guessing this was intended as a comment for RobinP's almost-duplicate answer.

Comment: See all events on your container in past hour : `docker events --filter container=my-worker --since '60m'`

Answer (score 0):

You can check with following command:

`docker system events --filter event=restart`

For more information :  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_events